# An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, upgrade

Hi i am getting the error below when i try and update my ubuntu server through command line:

> Reading cache
>
> Checking package manager
>
> Cannot upgrade
>
> An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.

i used the following commands to try and update:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
sudo apt autoremove
do-release-upgrade
```

im trying to upgrade from 17.04

my sourcelist content is:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).

Comment: i looked at that above and thats where i found the commands above to do it, yet i still get the same error. my sourcelist is clean too

Comment: *My sourcelist is clean too*: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: i will update my post above to show it

Comment: Ok it magically now working....